# How do I center align a two column list under a paragraph of text on a responsive website?

Tags: html, css

Please see the two screenshots. One screenshot shows the left column not centered. The second screenshot has both columns centered under the paragraph. I would like to achieve this result on a responsive website.

- Current Result
  [https://s11.postimg.org/bcu53jhhv/current_result.jpg][1]
- Intended Result
  [https://s11.postimg.org/9mb421zyr/intendend_result.jpg][2]

  ```
  <p align="center">
      One day I was walking in a forest. I sat down to catch my breath. I saw a spider and it startled me. I continued walking and saw a river. It began to rain. I did not have my rain boots on. I started to get wet so I hid under a tree. When the rain stopped, I began to walk home.
  </p>

  <div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
      <ul>
          <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i>   Item 1</li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i>   Item 2</li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i>   Item 3</li>
      </ul>
  </div>

  <div style="float: right; width: 50%;">
      <ul>
          <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i>   Item 4</li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i>   Item 5</li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i>   Item 6</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: Check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40914504/607874). You should use `column-count`.

Comment: image urls now 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make only one `<div>` as container and use `display: flex`.

It should be okay like that. Take a look at the multiple **CSS Flexbox** properties, it will keep your code correct and easier !

Here's how I'd do it :

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  /* it will calculate automatically, try space-between too */
}

#container ul {
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Item 1</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Item 2</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Item 3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Item 4</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Item 5</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Item 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding to me Aymeric Mayeux. I tested your code and it worked. https://jsfiddle.net/sd5sjtsb/

Comment: You're welcome @BrodyJames , and be sure that the **flexbox** is an easy way to organize the position of your HTML ;)
Don't forget to accept the answer you found most useful to your problem

Answer (score 2):

You should float the `ul` to the right to properly align it. Please check : https://jsfiddle.net/esx6fzyf/1/

```html
<p align="center">One day I was walking in a forest. I sat down to catch my breath. I saw a spider and it startled me. I
    continued walking and saw a river. It began to rain. I did not have my rain boots on. I started to get wet so I hid
    under a tree. When the rain stopped, I began to walk home.</p>

<div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
        <ul style="float: right;">
            <li>
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Item 1
            </li>
            <li>
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Item 2
            </li>
            <li>
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Item 3
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 50%;">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Item 4
            </li>
            <li>
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Item 5
            </li>
            <li>
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Item 6
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much SpartakusMd. I tested your code first and it worked like a charm. However, I would like to know how to take the two column list sand turn it into 1 column (responsive) when viewed on a mobile phone. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: You can do this via media queries. Setting the floats only if width is bigger than 768px for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add text-align: center below:

```html
<p>One day I was walking in a forest. I sat down to catch my breath. I saw a spider and it startled me. I continued walking and saw a river. It began to rain. I did not have my rain boots on. I started to get wet so I hid under a tree. When the rain stopped, I began to walk home.</p>

    <div style="width: 50%; float: left; text-align:center">
    <ul style="">
        <li>
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>   Item 1</li>
        <li>
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>   Item 2</li>
        <li>
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>   Item 3</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 50%; float: right; text-align:center">
    <ul style="text-align:left">
        <li>
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>   Test</li>
        <li>
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>   Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>   Item 6</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Like this the bullets and text are not properly displayed.

Comment: I edited the code above thats what you are looking for

Comment: an on mobile you could use a media query to display the contents differently if you wish you that the list items are not so compressed together

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CSS Flexbox**. Wrap your `<div>`s containing `<ul>` inside a parent div (in my case `.ul-holder`) and apply align properties, like:

```
.ul-holder {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center /* Horizontally aligns content in the center */
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.ul-holder {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.list {
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.list ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<p align="center">One day I was walking in a forest. I sat down to catch my breath. I saw a spider and it startled me. I continued walking and saw a river. It began to rain. I did not have my rain boots on. I started to get wet so I hid under a tree. When the rain stopped, I began to walk home.</p>

<div class="ul-holder">

    <div class="list">
    <ul>
        <li>
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>   Item 1</li>
        <li>
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>   Item 2</li>
        <li>
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>   Item 3</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="list">
    <ul>
        <li>
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>   Item 4</li>
        <li>
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>   Item 5</li>
        <li>
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>   Item 6</li>
    </ul>
      
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason not to use the awesome [column-count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count) property, as it has a good browser support.

I see that you created two lists for presentation purposes. This is conceptually wrong. You should never modify your information layer (HTML) to fit a particular presentation. Thats where the power of CSS3 comes to the rescue.

Web is all about information (html) + presentation (css) + behaviour (js).

Therefore, I've merged your two lists into a single one and used CSS to display it in two columns.
They are always centered, regardeless of the viewport width and the items length.

To test the responsiveness to content length, please type something on the **TYPE here** item.

```css
section {
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  -webkit-column-count: 2; 
  column-count: 2;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p>One day I was walking in a forest. I sat down to catch my breath. I saw a spider and it startled me. I continued walking and saw a river. It began to rain. I did not have my rain boots on. I started to get wet so I hid under a tree. When the rain stopped, I began to walk home.</p>
  <ul>
    <li contenteditable>
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>TYPE here
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Item 2
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Item 3
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Item 4
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Item 5
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Item 6
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Jose. I tested your code and it worked. However, I am attempting to fix the right column because it is displayed 1 or 2 lines higher than the left column.

Comment: @BrodyJames Probably because of your `<i>` tag. Again, to display a checkmark, you don't even need that tag, you can use `li:before` pseudo-class in CSS instead

Comment: @BrodyJames But if you really want to keep the `<i>` you can make it `li i { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 1em; }` and `li {position: relative;}`